# Explanation on c++ template syntax

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking at the following post [write a boost::multi_array to hdf5 dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250237/write-a-boostmulti-array-to-hdf5-dataset) and couldn't understand the syntax used for the templates in the first answer by Leo Goodstadt. Unfortunately I have not enough reputation to comment directly on the answer given there, that's why i've created this separate question.

As far as I understood this there's a struct created with a static method type() that returns the respective type.

This generic struct is then overwritten by one with a fixed type. But what exactly is written there in the curly braces , i.e. what is its meaning? For example, what is the meaning of the following:

```
{ H5::IntType type {   H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR
                   };  
};
```

within the first definition of the char-template:

```
template<> struct get_hdf5_data_type<char> {   
     H5::IntType type {   
         H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR       
    };  
};
```

I've copied below the essential parts of the definition of the template, but probably it's easier to look at the original post for a clear picture.

```
template<typename T> struct get_hdf5_data_type {   
    static H5::PredType type() {   
        //static_assert(false, "Unknown HDF5 data type"); 
        return H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE; 
    }
};
template<> struct get_hdf5_data_type<char> {   
    H5::IntType type { H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR };  
};
template<> struct get_hdf5_data_type<long long> {   
     H5::IntType type { H5::PredType::NATIVE_LLONG };  
};
template<> struct get_hdf5_data_type<unsigned long long> {   
     H5::IntType type { H5::PredType::NATIVE_ULLONG };  
};
template<> struct get_hdf5_data_type<int8_t> {   
    H5::IntType type { H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT8 };  
};
```

Comment: *Unfortunately I have not enough reputation to comment directly on the answer given there, that's why i've created this separate question.* - Hallelujah, the system works! Questions do belong in new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly syntax is initialisation

```
H5::IntType type    {   H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR       };
```

Is similar to

```
H5::IntType type = H5::PredType::NATIVE_CHAR;
```

I'm not familiar with H5, but the OP then uses it as `hdf_data_type.type` which is just refering to a particular type previously defined in your list of specialisations.

Now `hdf_data_type` needs to be of one of the provided template specialisations, `get_hdf5_data_type<char>` for instance to provide the definition for type.

The commented out static_assert in the generic template could be used as a marker that no known specialisation has been found and the object `hdf_data_type` is not useful.

Comment: thanks for you answer, the syntax is now clear to me. But isn't the method type() useless, since when no known specialisation is found you get a function pointer instead of a type?

Comment: I've tried to compile the code of the OP but it seems like this syntax is not working as the compilation fails with: **main.cpp:32:15: error: function definition does not declare parameters**

Comment: @Udo As for your first question, that would depend on usage, but it is my impression that the intention is to fail the compilation with the static_assert. And the different specializations are unrelated types.  As for 2 - it probably deserves a new question as I'm unable to deduce what line the error refers to.